# Avoiding Repetition in Nested Conditional

Tags: javascript, optimization, code-readability

With a nested conditional similar to the following, how might you optimize the branches for enhanced performance and/or readability? Because there are loops within many of the potential cases, it would be more efficient to consolidate the repetitive entries into a more practical function.

```
//a is defined either 1, 2, or 3
//b is defined either true or false

for(var i=0; i<hugeNumber; i++){
switch(a){
    case 1:
        if(b){
            for(objects in longlist){
                objects.color = object.c;
                objects.position = object.x
            }
        }else{
            for(objects in longlist){
                objects.color = object.c;
                objects.position = object.y
            }
    case 2:
        if(b){
            for(objects in longlist){
                objects.color = object.b;
                objects.position = object.x;
            }
        }else{
            for(objects in longlist){
                objects.color = object.b;
                objects.position = object.y;
            }
    case 3:
        if(b){
            for(objects in longlist){
                objects.color = blackColor;
                objects.position = object.x;
            }
        }else{
            for(objects in longlist){
                objects.color = blackColor;
                objects.position = object.y;
            }
}
}
```

It appears just as unreasonable to place the conditionals within an overarching for loop.

Ideally the target variable could be defined at the beginning, immediately when the conditions are known - as conditional a always yields color c for 0, color b for 1, and blackColor for 2, while conditional b always yields position x for true and position y for false.

I have seen variations of this question for PHP and Ruby, but am not quite sure how to apply the solutions to JavaScript. I can think of some ways that this might work, but I have so far not been able to make the code function syntactically.

**UPDATE / SOLUTION:** An answer prompted me to discover that this can be accomplished efficiently with `eval()`:

```
var targetColor;
var targetPosition;

switch(a){
    case 1: targetColor = "objects.c"; break;
    case 2: targetColor = "objects.b"; break;
    case 3: targetColor = "blackColor"; break;
}
if(b){
    targetPosition = "objects.x";
}else{
    targetPosition = "objects.y";
}

for(var i=0; i<hugeNumber; i++){
    for(objects in longlist){
        objects.color = eval(targetColor);
        objects.position = eval(targetPosition);
    }
}
```

If there is a better approach than this I am absolutely open to additional suggestions - I know that eval can be sometimes dangerous.

Comment: What are `object.c` and `object.x`? Are they properties in the objects of `longlist`?

Comment: That is correct - they are properties of the objects.

Comment: Please show the code in one of the `for (objects in longlist){...` section.

Comment: @thefourtheye Updated - the use of comments was definitely obfuscating the problem at hand, thanks.

Comment: @XLXMXNT The solution you have added works pretty like the one I previously posted from a performance point of view. Apart from your `stringToVariable` function that is not a native function, what is not clear for you in your second snippet?

Comment: @guari I agree, after reading your answer I determined that I needed to use `eval()`. As your answer solves the proposed question, I have marked it as correct.

Comment: thanks :) Anyway be careful with `eval`, use it only if you know for sure what is passed to it as string (eg. look at the closure chain and evaluate the possibility to add a regex check on the content of the string if necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little less compact but quite readable and without unnecessary rechecks:

```
var coord = b ? 'x' : 'y';
var col = '';
switch(a){
    case 1: col = 'c';
    case 2: col = 'b';
    // may add more cases...
}
for(objects in longlist) {
    object.color = object[col] || 'blackColor';
    object.position = object[coord];
}
```

Comment: I am marking this as the correct solution because it takes into account that the object's own properties, and not global variables, determine the values that it uses. This answer has also prompted me to use `eval()` as a current solution to the problem (see updated question). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
var colorToBeApplied = (a === 0 ? "c" : (a === 1 ? "b" : "blackColor"));
var position = b ? "x" : "y";

for(objects in longlist) {
    objects.color    = colorToBeApplied;
    objects.position = position;
}
```

If you could show the code inside the for loop, it will be better to optimize.

Comment: This makes sense, but using the ternary operator inside the "else" block of another ternary operator is not very readable. I would go with an `if` statement for that.

Comment: @ThomasUpton I was actually thinking about `var colorToBeApplied = a === 1 || a === 0 ? String.fromCharCode('c'.charCodeAt(0) - a) : "blackColor";`

Comment: The problem with this is that each object's `objects.color` should be set to its corresponding `objects.c` or `objects.b`, and not a global variable `c` or `b`. Something like `objects.color = objects[colorToBeApplied]` would work, but this would be broken for the case where `objects.color = blackColor`

Answer (score 0):

Using the logic you have described, I find this to be a decent place between minimum amount of lines and readability.

```
for(objects in longList) {
    object.pos = b ? x : y;
    switch(a) {
        case 1: object.color = c;
        case 2: object.color = b;
        case 3: object.color = backColor;
    }
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear - the use of comments may have been misleading. Your solution certainly works to condense the code, but consider the following: The problem with this is that each object's `objects.color` should be set to its corresponding `objects.c` or `objects.b`, and not a global variable `c` or `b`. Something like `objects.color = objects[colorToBeApplied]` would work, but this would be broken for the case where `objects.color = blackColor`

Comment: Shouldn't my solution still work? Just replace the global variables to use properties of `object`.

Comment: My concern is that this solution is too process intensive, because the case must be checked for every object in longlist. As the cases are defined at the beginning, I'm looking for some way to first determine which variables to use, and then to loop through the objects and set their values appropriately. I updated the question again with a 'mock' solution. Thanks again for the feedback, this seems to be my fault in not articulating the issue correctly.